# filling empty nested lists - for loop vs list comprehension

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension, nested-lists

Trying to fill empty nested lists with a value, I found there is different behavior between using a for loop vs list comprehension, and I was wondering why this is, despite functionally they should do the same. See below:

```
nl= [[True], []]

for item in nl:
    if len(item) ==0:
        item.append('false')
#this is the desired result
print(nl)
[[True], ['false']]

nl=[item.append('false') for item in nl if len(item)==0]
print(nl)
[None]
#no idea why this happens
print([item.append('false') for item in nl if len(item)==0]
print(nl)
[[True], ['false']]
```

Comment: " despite functionally they should do the same." **list comprehensions are not for loops** You shouldn't think of them as such. **Do not use list comprehensions for side-effects**. List comprehensions are for mapping/filtering operations on iterables which create lists. You are mapping `.append` to every item, but `.append` returns `None`

Comment: Please read https://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/ to understand how to use list comprehensions generally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `item.append()` does not return anything (i.e. it returns `None`). So your list comprehension is making a list of `None`.

You can change it to:

```py
nl=[['false'] if len(item)==0 else item for item in nl]
```

Comment: Thanks, what would be the correct way of appending the empty list via list comprehension?

Comment: I've added it to the answer

Comment: @Rizakha **you don't do that with list comprehensions** List comprehensions are for creating *new* lists. Don't use them for side effects. They are not "single line for loops*.

Comment: Thanks! Marked as correct since you astutely pointed out the correct structure for the output

Answer (score 1):

List comprehension constructs list from the values returned `.append()` does it in place, so you need not to use append and you can use handsome if shorthand ;-)

```
nl= [[True], []]
nl = [['false'] if not item else item for item in nl]
print(nl)
```

Comment: This doesn't produce OP's expected outcome. This results in `[['True'], 'false']` whereas OP wants `[['True'], ['false']]`

Comment: That "shorthand" doesn't look particularly short compared to `item or ['false']`.

Answer (score 0):

```
nl= [[True], []]

[item.append('false') for item in nl if len(item)==0]
print(nl)
```

Something like this would work, but I'm not sure why you'd want to do it this way. The list comprehension isn't returning anything, so printing or assigning it would just return None.